# Exact one matching value in list of object where object consist 4 properties

Tags: java, list, collections, java-7

I have a list of my class object (EmployerDetails). Employer Details consist 4 parameters. List may contain all object with different parameters or parameters may be same for more than 1 object in that list. 
My Class is something like this :

```
    public class EmployerDetails {

    private String employerId;
    private String occupationCode;
    private String SchemeCategory;
    private String switchingFlag;
}
```

I have used ArrayList to retrieve the objects.

Suppose I have a list of 10 employer object with data set like this:

Employer Id is same in all 10 objects.

OccupationCode is same in 4 objects, different in 5 object and null in one object.

SchemeCategory is different in 9 object and null in one object.

switchingFlag could be either Y or N.

Now my problem is, I have one **occupationCode** and one **schemeCategory** with me and I have to retrieve the object which satisfies my condition and the condition is : Records with same employerId (which is above example are 10), I have to retrieve the record which matches my occupationCode and there should be exactly one match. For example if my OccupationCode matches with 4 objects, I will skip this condition and proceed to condition 2 which is  : I will retrieve the record where occupationCode is not null and schemeCategory matches my schemeCategory. and again third condition.

Currently I'm iterating the list using for each loop, in condition 1 if occupationCode of object matches with my OccupationCode, it will go inside if condition. In above example it will go 4 times but while iterating I have to retrieve the record only if there is one match.

I could use counter and put the object in HashMap and after for loop completes if count ==1, retrieve the object but problem here is, I have 4 conditions like this and I have to write for loop for all conditions and after iterating, if there is no result then again I have to iterate for condition 2 and so on.

Is there any solution to problem like this? I'm using Java 7 and can't use Java 8.

Thanks.

Comment: *Is there any solution to problem like this?* Yes, there probably is. What is your actual question?

Comment: what is the shortest way of doing that? As per my logic, I have to use for loop for all conditions.

Comment: There is no way to avoid loops, if that's your question. How about you post the code you have, on codereview.stackexchange.com, instead of asking us to provide the code for you?

Comment: Before you post code on [CodeReview.SE], make sure that it's actually [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Comment: Hi Nizet, I was not having the exact code with me right now but I have typed the sample code. 
 https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174647/exact-one-matching-value-in-list-of-object-where-object-consist-4-properties

Answer (score 0):

I could think of 2 solutions
Assuming you have these info to match employerId, occupationCode,SchemeCategory and switchingFlag ->

**Solution1:**
Form a string by concatenating all of these 4 values - lets call it expectedAggregateString. In EmployerDetails class add this method

```
private String getAggregatedStringVal() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(employerId);
        str.append(occupationCode);
        str.append(SchemeCategory);
        str.append(switchingFlag);
        return str.toString();
    }
```

In a single loop- iterate through the list and compare the expectedAggregateString with each of the loop object's getAggregatedStringVal method.
The first match - break off the loop.

**Solution 2:**
Instead of string, create an expected EmployerDetails  object since as per my assumption you have all 4 values required for the EmployerDetails obj.
In EmployerDetails  class generate equals() and hashcode() method and in a single loop compare each of the objects from the loop with expected EmployerDetails  objects. The first match - break off the loop.

Comment: My requirement is, I have to match the occupationCode with the occupationCode in list object, if there is no match or more than one match then I have to check second condition and if there is no match then I have to check third condition and so on. I don't think that is possible with the solution provided.  please refer the code : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174647/exact-one-matching-value-in-list-of-object-where-object-consist-4-properties

Comment: The solution you provided will work if there is only one condition but I have to check more than 3 conditions and I've to check in that sequence only.